# How to hide axis tick labels in plotly

Tags: plotly-python, radar-chart

my code is this

```
import plotly.express as px
theta = ["PAC", "SHO", "PHY", "PAS", "DEF", "DRI"]
    values = [player.pace, player.shooting, player.physic, player.passing, player.defending_sliding_tackle, player.dribbling]

    fig = px.line_polar(
                        r=values,
                        theta=theta,
                        line_close=True,
                        range_r = [0,100],
                        title="PLAYER SKILL DIAGRAM",
    )

    fig.update_layout(yaxis={'visible': False, 'showticklabels': False}, xaxis={'visible': False, 'showticklabels': False})

    fig.update_yaxes(title='y', visible=False, showticklabels=False)
    fig.update_xaxes(title='x', visible=False, showticklabels=False)
```

The resulting image is this

[Radar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NwpX.png)

I can't hide the tick labels no matter what.

Sorry for the dreadful formatting. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The axis in a polar plot is called neither x-axis nor y-axis, but radial axis and angular axis.

Thus, you can hide the radial tick labels by adding the following command:

```
fig.update_layout(polar = dict(radialaxis = dict(showticklabels = False)))
```

If you also want to hide the circle lines, write:

```
fig.update_layout(polar = dict(radialaxis = dict(visible = False)))
```

Correspondingly, the angular axis tick labels, can be hidden by:

```
fig.update_layout(polar = dict(angularaxis = dict(showticklabels = False)))
```

Answer (score 0):

- have simulated `player`
- simple case of `fig.update_layout(polar_angularaxis_showticklabels=False)`

#### full code

```
import plotly.express as px
from types import SimpleNamespace
import random
from types import SimpleNamespace

player = SimpleNamespace(**{m:random.randint(20,50) for m in ["pace", "shooting", "physic", "passing", "defending_sliding_tackle", "dribbling"]})

theta = ["PAC", "SHO", "PHY", "PAS", "DEF", "DRI"]
values = [player.pace, player.shooting, player.physic, player.passing, player.defending_sliding_tackle, player.dribbling]

fig = px.line_polar(
                    r=values,
                    theta=theta,
                    line_close=True,
                    range_r = [0,100],
                    title="PLAYER SKILL DIAGRAM",
)


fig.update_layout(polar_angularaxis_showticklabels=False)
```

[image]